# How to fill a DropDown using Jquery Ajax Call?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a WebMethod which gets data that I want to fill DropDown with in a DataSet. 
Currently I am filling the dropdown using a hardcoded object. But I want to replace this hard coded object with data returned by webmethod.

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
         public static string GetDropDownDataWM(string name)
         {
             //return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
             //    + DateTime.Now.ToString();

             var msg = "arbaaz";

             string[] name1 = new string[1];
             string[] Value = new string[1];
             name1[0] = "@Empcode";
             Value[0] = HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginUser"].ToString().Trim();
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             dboperation dbo = new dboperation();
             ds = dbo.executeProcedure("GetDropDownsForVendor", name1, Value, 1);

             return ds.GetXml(); 

         }
```

**CLIENT SIDE(UPDATE 1):**

```
  <script type = "text/javascript">
    function GetDropDownData() {
        var myDropDownList = $('.myDropDownLisTId');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.aspx/GetDropDownDataWM",
            data: '{name: "abc" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(data.d), function () {
                    myDropDownList.append($("<option></option>").val(this['FieldDescription']).html(this['FieldCode']));
                });
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        console.log(response.d);
        alert(response.d);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is your response look like?

Comment: @Arbaaz, does the code that you have edited (in your Q) work?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
function GetDropDownData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "test.aspx/GetDropDownDataWM",
        data: '{name: "abc" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data.d)
                {
                    $.each(data.d, function (){
                        $(".myDropDownLisTId").append($("<option     />").val(this.KeyName).text(this.ValueName));
                    });
                },
        failure: function () {
            alert("Failed!");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `WebMethod`, don't send `DataSet` directly, send `XML`...

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetDropDownDataWM(string name)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.Tables.Add("Table0");
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("OptionValue");
    ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("OptionText");
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add("0", "test 0");
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add("1", "test 1");
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add("2", "test 2");
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add("3", "test 3");
    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add("4", "test 4");

    return ds.GetXml();
}
```

Before *Ajax* call...

```
var myDropDownList = $('.myDropDownLisTId');
```

Try like below...(inside *Ajax* call)

```
success: function (response) {
    debugger;

    $(response.d).find('Table0').each(function () {
           var OptionValue = $(this).find('OptionValue').text();
           var OptionText = $(this).find('OptionText').text();
           var option = $("<option>" + OptionText + "</option>");
           option.attr("value", OptionValue);

           myDropDownList.append(option);
     });
},
```

**Note:**

1. `OptionValue` and `OptionText` are the Columns of `DataSet` Table.
2. `$(response.d).find('Table0').each(function (){})` - Here `Table0`
   is the name of Table inside `DataSet`.

Comment: But where do I call the GetDropDownData()?  In filldd() right?

Comment: @Arbaaz Yes, in that `filldd()` function.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error

Comment: look at his fiddle .. http://jsfiddle.net/a4NSm/5/

I want to fill the dropdown with data returned by server instead of hardcoded object.

Comment: 500 Errors means that the URL is wrong. Are you sure that URL `test.aspx/GetDropDownDataWM` is correct?

Comment: I am positive. That's the url. And as far as I know incorrect URL will give `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Okay, let me try this at my end. Please wait.

Comment: @Arbaaz Finally it is done. Yes there was a 500 Error issue due to DataSet Serialization issue. I am updating the answer now.

Comment: I am still getting same error. Let me check what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Arbaaz So, is there any problem now?

Comment: yeah, same old 500! :P

Comment: Do one thing now. Select the POST request on Console Tab and see all the tabs. "Json" - this tab would give you the data returned. Does it show one XML?

Comment: :P how do I select POSt in Console?

Comment: My mozilla doesnt look like that but I cant find any xml there . I am however returning XML from codebehind using GetXMl()

Comment: I have updated my clientside code again , I am able to populate dropdown now, but now I am using JSON instead of  XML. And I am sending DataTable instead of DataSet. If you can tell me how I can do this with DataSet, I will mark your answer.

Comment: @Arbaaz I guess you have used Serializer Classes for that. I just tried to give you the simplest one to deal with this using `XML`. However, good work !!! And about `DataSet`, as I don't know how you exactly achieved this using `DataTable`, so how can I tell you about `DataSet`?

Comment: +1  
Please take a look at my new question `http://stackoverflow.com/q/23079067/2064292`

Answer (score 1):

```
 var theDropDown = document.getElementById("myDropDownLisTId");
                theDropDown.length = 0;
                $.each(items, function (key, value) {

                    $("#myDropDownLisTId").append($("<option></option>").val(value.PKId).html(value.SubDesc));
```

here "SubDesc",PKId describes the value getting out of Database., u need to separate your value from dataset.

Answer (score 0):

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
     public static string GetDropDownDataWM(string name)
     {
         //return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
         //    + DateTime.Now.ToString();

         var msg = "arbaaz";

         string[] name1 = new string[1];
         string[] Value = new string[1];
         name1[0] = "@Empcode";
         Value[0] = HttpContext.Current.Session["LoginUser"].ToString().Trim();
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         dboperation dbo = new dboperation();
         ds = dbo.executeProcedure("GetDropDownsForVendor", name1, Value, 1);

         return DataSetToJSON(ds); 

     }

public static string DataSetToJSON(DataSet ds)
{

    Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
    {
        object[] arr = new object[dt.Rows.Count + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray;
        }

        dict.Add(dt.TableName, arr);
    }

    var lstJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
    return lstJson;
}
```

Ajax Call

```
function GetAssociation() {

        var myDropDownList = $("#myDropDownLisTId");
        var post_data = JSON.stringify({ "name": "xyz"});
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.aspx/GetDropDownDataWM",
            data: post_data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                json_data = JSON.parse(response.d);
                myDropDownList.empty();
                for(i=0; i<json_data.Table.length; i++)
                {

                    myDropDownList.append($("<option></option>").val(json_data.Table[i][0]).html(json_data.Table[i][1]));
                }

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// We can bind dropdown list using this Jquery function in JS script
   

function listDropdownBind() {
  var requestId = 123; 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/ControllerName/ActionName?param=" + param, // call API with parameter
        headers: { 'rId': requestId },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function (data) {
            var optionhtml1 = '';
            var optionhtml1 = '<option value="' +
                0 + '">' + "--Select--" + '</option>';
            $("#ddlName").append(optionhtml1);

            $.each(data, function (i) {

                var optionhtml = '<option value="' +
                    data.d[i].Value + '">' + data.d[i].Text + '</option>';
                $("#ddlName").append(optionhtml);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.