# How to extract DataTable from DataSet which is in JSON format

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I am using Newtonsoft dll for serialization. I am currently returning DataTable from webmethod in Json Format.  And it works fine. But I want to do the same thing by returning DataSet instead of a DataTable. I tried a number of things but none seem to be working.

```
function GetDropDownData() {
        var myDropDownList = $('.myDropDownLisTId');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.aspx/GetDropDownDataWM",
            data: '{name: "abc" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(jQuery.parseJSON(data.d), function () {
                    myDropDownList.append($("<option></option>").val(this['id']).html(this['name']));
                });
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
        });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        console.log(response.d);
        alert(response.d);
    }
```

**Json DataTable Returned:**

`[{"name":"sam","id":"1"},{"name":"mark","id":"2"}]`

**Json DataSet Returned:**

```
 {"patients":[{"name":"sam","id":"1"},{"name":"mark","id":"2"}],"medications":[{"id":"1","medication":"atenolol"},{"id":"2","medication":"amoxicillin"}]}
```

**Fiddle**
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8kkg3/306/)

`var json=jsonds['patients'];` with `var json=data['patients'];`

Comment: Ya then whats the problem you want to extract the values like datatable from this dataset?

Comment: As you can see I am filling dropdown with datatable at the moment.But I want to do this using Dataset. So that I dont have to send requests to server again and again for different dropdowns. I am not able to extract single datatable from dataset.

Comment: ok get it posting answer

Comment: please check the answer i posted

Comment: I did. I commented there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I succeeded.

Inside `Ajax` *Success*, do like below...

```
var dataSet = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
var dataTable = dataSet["patients"];

$.each(dataTable, function () {
    myDropDownList.append($("<option></option>").val(this['id']).html(this['name']));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var aa={"patients":[{"name":"sam","id":"1"},{"name":"mark","id":"2"}],"medications":[{"id":"1","medication":"atenolol"},{"id":"2","medication":"amoxicillin"}]}
console.log(aa["patients"]);
console.log(aa["medications"]);
```

This is just a example

You can see that when you have two level json object you have to use it with the name

and your object will be like the datatable

Please check the demo here [Demo](http://jsbin.com/kevocaga/1/)

Comment: Your demo link is not working. And even if it works by hard coding it. I am not sure how to implement it in my code . 
This is what I have tried http://jsfiddle.net/8kkg3/306/

It works in jsfiddle but it does not work in my code when i try to replace `var json=jsonds['patients'];` with `var json=data['patients'];`

Comment: Please check console man there you will get object okay indeed you got answer at last

Comment: This does not work with  `console.log(data["patients"]);`
                `console.log(data["medication"]);`

Comment: console.log(data["patients"]); gives me undifined while  console.log(aa["patients"]); gives me object in console

Comment: Ya man i just give you example you have to implement it like `aa["patients"]`