# How To get Selected Tex from asp.net Dropdown codeBehind After Bind through JQuery Ajax Calling

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have Bind asp.net dropDwon by Jquery ajax Call .now i want selected text from code behind. 
How?

```
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropdownCounty" DataValueField="id" DataTextField="name" AppendDataBoundItems="True" onchange="populateState();">

                    </asp:DropDownList>

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "webservice/WebService1.asmx/getCountry",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        success: function (response) {

                            $("#DropdownCounty").empty();
                            $("#DropdownCounty").append('<option value="0">Please select</option>');
                            $.each(response.d, function (key, value) {
                                $("#DropdownCounty").append($("<option></option>").val(value.id).text(value.name));
                            })
                                },
                        failure: function (response) {

                            alert(response.d);
                        }

                    });
```

Code behind

var dasd = DropdownCounty.SelectedValue;

Comment: AJAX doesn't bind anything, AJAX is for making HTTP requests. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question so that it makes sense.

Comment: My guess, **you** **should** **consider** **editing** **your** **question** **to** **help** **people** **understand** **it**, is that you dont know how to get using javascript the value of a dropdown after and ajax made call has changed the iitem selected.

Comment: i just did save as 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955839/how-to-fill-a-dropdown-using-jquery-ajax-call
but from codebehind Selected text in empty string

Comment: You have a drop down in your page, in Ajax call gets this control value and send to back end, in your action method you should add this parameter

Comment: OK, you have retrieved the dropdown data via and ajax call and after data is retrieved you have populated the html control. Your question is not related with databindings or ajax, but with javascript/jquery.

Comment: Looks like you are using jquery. This question looks duplicated of  [jQuery Get Selected Option From Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659097/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Answer (score 0):

Show us your code for a better reply but I think you you can try

```
var value =yourDropDownList.SelectedValue
```

Comment: I think his problem is not server side but client side (check the question comments). Because of that this answer is probably wrong.