# How can i fill a DropDown list using ajax and a c# method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

Hi my c#  method is this:

```
[WebMethod] 
    protected static void fillList(HiddenField hiddenControl, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList listinc)
    {
        int dato = 0;
        string strSql;
        dato = Convert.ToInt32(hiddenControl.Value);

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString());
        conn.Open();
        strSql = "SELECT DISTINCT incid FROM HisReportes WHERE peri = " + dato;
        SqlCommand camAND = new SqlCommand(strSql, conn);
        System.Data.DataTable tablainc = new System.Data.DataTable();
        camAND.CommandTimeout = 36000;
        tablainc.Load(camAND.ExecuteReader());

        foreach (DataRow dtrw in tablainc.Rows)
        {            
           listinc.Items.Add(dtrw[0].ToString());
        }

    }
```

i tested with a onlick function and it works but i need to call it from Ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Incio.aspx/fillList",
        data: '{hiddenControl , listinc, dtrw }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)
            {
                $.each(data, function (){
                    $("listinc").append($("<option     />").val(this.incidente).text(this.dtrw[0]));
                });
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert("Failed!");
            }
        });
```

that's my ajax function but it is not filling the dropdown list.

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error-message?

Comment: It doesn't fill the dropdown list.

Comment: So you don't get an error message? Does the `alert` go off?

Comment: Yes the alert is working with the message "fail"

Comment: A lot of weird thigs are going on with this code. First `fillList` method takes 2 parameters but your ajax sends just one parameter and its not even match. Second your code open to SQL injections. I think you need to know how Client/Server side communicate. You can check [How to fill a DropDown using Jquery Ajax Call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955839/how-to-fill-a-dropdown-using-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: based on what i see, your url parameter is wrong

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: `that's my ajax function but it is not working.` isn't a question; are there errors, please update your post to include relevant information for us to replicate to help you.

Comment: the error is likely a 404

Comment: try this instead url: 'Inicio.aspx/fillList'

Comment: im going to edit my AJAX function @SelimYıldız, please check it.

Comment: I have edited my post, and aslo the AJAX function, now the error message is not appearing but the droplist is still empty.

Comment: your method isnt returning the data for the ajax call to consume, it is void. you need to return the data you want to push into the dropdownlist

Comment: Should i return the List?

Comment: yes return the list you built in the method, then iterate over it in the ajax call to populate the dropdownlist.

Comment: Can you please write a little example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to return the list from your WebMethod, I recommended you to return a string array from the WebMethod.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string[] fillList()
    {
        your code here....
        return listinc.ToArray();
    }
```

So, into Ajax in the success function

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "./Inicio.aspx/fillList",
      ...
      success: function (data) {
          let data = data["d"];
          let dropdown = $("#listinc");

          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // put here your data
            dropdown.append(`<option>${ data[i] }</option>`);
          }
       }
    });
```

Comment: You are going to have to pass in that Hidden Field value in your web method so he can use in the SQL statement

Comment: Sure, this is only an example.